# How to Handle fetch and add Integer value from nested ArrayList to List

Tags: java, arraylist

Im getting following message

```
java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

While trying to fetch the values from nested 
`arraylist<Object>  listsALL`
and add the value in to 
`list<Integer> listPriceFinal`

```
listPriceFinal.add(Integer.valueOf((Integer)listsALL.get(2)));
```

listsALL contains Integer, String Values

example :

```
listsALL------------- [[0, 1, 5, 4, 6], [250, 260], [230], [Item 1, Item 2, Item 6], [Item 5, Item 7]]
```

While trying with String value I didn’t get any issues. 
Like

```
sItems100.add(String.valueOf(listsALL.get(4)));
```

How to resolve or how to handle for Integer, Please any one help in this…..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may help:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Object> listsAll = new ArrayList<Object>();
        listsAll.add(Arrays.asList(new Integer[] { 12, 45, 78 }));
        listsAll.add(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "s12", "s45", "s78" }));

        List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        intList.addAll((List<Integer>) listsAll.get(0));

        List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
        strList.addAll((List<String>) listsAll.get(1));

        System.out.println(listsAll);
        System.out.println(intList);
        System.out.println(strList);
    }
}
```

You will get the output as:

```
[[12, 45, 78], [s12, s45, s78]]
[12, 45, 78]
[s12, s45, s78]
```

The idea is to cast the object from the parent `List` to `List<Integer>` or `List<String>`.

Comment: Thanks for your response and i got the solution from your example. yes its working for me.          listPriceFinal.addAll((List<Integer>) listsALL.get(2));

Answer (score 2):

When you call `listsALL.get(2)` you are getting an array. In your example you are getting [230].

That's the cause of the error. You cannot cast the array [230] to an Integer.

Instead you should get an item of the array. For example: `((int[])listsALL.get(2))[0]`

So it would be: `listPriceFinal.add(Integer.valueOf( ((int[])listsALL.get(2))[0] ));`

**If the internal items are not simple arrays, but ArrayList's, so you need to use:**

```
listPriceFinal.add(Integer.valueOf( ((ArrayList)listsALL.get(2)).get(0) ));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response , when i tried with listPriceFinal.add(Integer.valueOf( ((int[])listsALL.get(2))[0] )); i got an messgae - java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to [I. can you please advice me how to resolve this?

Comment: Try this: listPriceFinal.add(Integer.valueOf( ((ArrayList)listsALL.get(2)).get(0) ));

Comment: Thanks for your help and i got the solution. listPriceFinal.addAll((List<Integer>) listsALL.get(2));

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question right, but you're trying to use `String.valueOf()` to get something and add it to an integer array? [The `valueOf()` returns a String](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_valueof.htm). If you want the integer, use something like [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_parseint.htm).

Comment: No,for Integer i use Integer ArrayList, for String - String ArrayList.